# Hibernate mapping ManyToMany (не записывает в базу)

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

В базу не записываются связные ауди в таблицу, которая должна была бы генерировать поля автоматически. 
Вот код базы:

```
CREATE TABLE place_type( 
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  name character varying(255),
  file character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT placetype_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE place (
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  name character varying(255),
  file character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT place_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE place_type_has_place (
  place_type_id bigserial NOT NULL, 
  place_id bigserial NOT NULL, 
  CONSTRAINT place_type_has_place_pkey PRIMARY KEY(place_type_id, place_id),
  CONSTRAINT place_type_has_place_fkey FOREIGN KEY(place_id)
  REFERENCES place(id),
  CONSTRAINT place_type_has_place_type_fkey FOREIGN KEY(place_type_id)
  REFERENCES place_type(id) 
  );
```

Это сами ентити:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="place_type")
public class PlaceType {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column
private Long id;

@JoinColumn(name = "name")
private String name;

@JoinColumn(name="file")
private String file;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
        name="place_type_has_place",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "place_type_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "place_id")}
    )
private Set<Place> places = new HashSet<Place>();
// getter setter 
}
```

Ентити Place:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Place {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column
private Long id;

@JoinColumn(name = "name")
private String name;

@JoinColumn(name="file")
private String file;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="places", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<PlaceType> placeTypes = new HashSet<PlaceType>();

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
        name="place_has_menu",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "place_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "menu_id")}
    )
private Set<Menu> menus = new HashSet<Menu>();
//getters setters
}
```

Контроллер в котором обрабатывается добавления нового ентити Плейс в базу, в результате чего в таблице place_type_has_place должна добавится запись с айди нового плейса и его плейс_тайп. 
Новый плейс в базу добавляется, а таблица place_type_has_place остается пустой.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/savePlace", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String savePlace(PlaceForm placeForm, HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response, BindingResult result)
        throws ServletRequestBindingException, IOException {

    MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request;
    MultipartFile multipartFile = multipartRequest.getFile("file");

    System.out.println(placeForm.getPlaceType());
    Place place = new Place();

    place.setName(placeForm.getName());

    place.setFile(fileService.saveFile(multipartFile, "place"));

    Set<PlaceType> placeTypes = new HashSet<PlaceType>();
    PlaceType placeType = placeTypeService.getPlaceTypeById(placeForm.getPlaceType());
    placeTypes.add(placeType);
    place.setPlaceTypes(placeTypes);

    placeService.addPlace(place);

    return "redirect:addPlace";
}
```

С JSP все айди и все остальное в котроллер передается правильно. Никаких нулл и тд. Но все равно, что уже не пробовал, оно не хочет добавлять айди в связную таблицу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Точно не скажу почему не работает, но смущает пара-тройка вещей в Вашем примере.

1) Разве так делается двунаправленное отношение многие-ко-многим?
Одна сторона вроде должна быть владельцем отношения, другая использовать mappedBy.

2) Вы устанавливаете отношение только в одном направлении `place.setPlaceTypes(placeTypes)`.
А по правилам JPA (судя по аннотациям используется JPA) должны устанавливать в обоих.
Т.е. Каждый `placeType` из `placeTypes` должен выполнить `placeType.getPlaces().add(place)`

3) Может вместо:

```
Set<PlaceType> placeTypes = new HashSet<PlaceType>();
PlaceType placeType = placeTypeService.getPlaceTypeById(placeForm.getPlaceType());
placeTypes.add(placeType);
place.setPlaceTypes(placeTypes);
```

лучше сделать так:

```
PlaceType placeType = placeTypeService.getPlaceTypeById(placeForm.getPlaceType());
place.getPlaceTypes().add(placeType);
```

Это конечно не ошибка (по крайней мере в данном случае), только лишней работы себе создаёте.

С учётом пп 2 и 3. Должно быть так:

```
PlaceType placeType = placeTypeService.getPlaceTypeById(placeForm.getPlaceType());
// установка отношения в прямом направлении
place.getPlaceTypes().add(placeType);
// установка отношения в обратном направлении
placeType.getPlaces().add(place);
```

Думаю причина в п 2. Потому что со стороны placeType не установлено отношение с place и при записи в базу отменяется и прямая установка place.placeType.
Установка в прямом направлении создает запись. "Неустановка" в обратном тут же удаляет.
В совокупности с п 1. Если не ошибаюсь, то правильно сделав установку отношения в обоих направлениях, при таком mapping-е как у Вас получите две записи в join-таблице вместо одной.

Comment: Все я исправил. Я нашел костыль, как можно было добавить все таки это заведение, но ваш вариант, однозначно правильнее. Спасибо огромное, что избавили меня от такого тяжелого костыля.
Я как-то совсем забыл об обратной связи оказывается)